# Restore not working

Tags: backup, restore, data-loss, data-corruption

I'm new to Linux- (trying to leave Windows 10 with my customers and seeking alternatives besides iOS)
I have been working with Ubuntu for 4 months and have spread it to my first customers, but unfortunately today I had an ugly system crash on **Ubuntu 15.10** losing all data. *I was not able to repair it with grub (partition that Ubuntu was on said error and was not accessible which came at boot).

I reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10 in (recreated partition) and tried to restore my files from backup (external HDD which is OK !!). Unfortunately after completing 30% the backup stops with: **duplicity error** and says there is a **corrupt sigtar file**. OK but I have more than vol288 sigtar files (which I can copy without problem from external HDD etc.). If one file is lost this is not the problem, but losing the complete backup would be pretty awful.

My question therefore is: is there any possibility of restoring all the sigtar files which are fine and proceeding with the restore despite the error message (and corrupted sigtar files)?

Comment: Check out this page on the developer's website: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase